# how do I add the functionality of auto-filling the address when entered the PIN CODE in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api, pin-code

This is my html file, where I want that when a user fills the PIN CODE, the rest of the addresses like DISTRICT, STATE and CITY should be auto filled using the API data.

The API is: https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/244713

```
<div class="cardParts5">
                <div class="cardTitle">
                    Communication Address
                </div>

                <div class="addressContainer">
                  
                    <div class="field1">
                        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill" class="mat-form">
                            <mat-label>Pin Code*</mat-label>
                            <input matInput maxlength="6" [(ngModel)]="pinCode" name="pinCode">
                            <button (click)="getAdd(pinCode)">home</button>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field2">
                        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill" class="mat-form">
                            <mat-label>State*</mat-label>
                            <input matInput>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field3">
                        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill" class="mat-form">
                            <mat-label>District*</mat-label>
                            <input matInput>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field4">
                        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill" class="mat-form">
                            <mat-label>City/Village*</mat-label>
                            <input matInput>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

this is my **component.ts** file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-final-pay',
  templateUrl: './final-pay.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./final-pay.component.css']
})



export class FinalPayComponent implements OnInit {
  pinDetails:any;
  finalAddress:any;
  public pinCode = '';

  constructor( private httpClient: HttpClient ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }
  
  getAdd(pinCode){
      this.http.get(`https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/${pinCode}`).subscribe((val)=>{
        this.pinDetails = JSON.stringify(val);
        this.finalAddress = JSON.parse(this.pinDetails);
        console.log(this.finalAddress);
    });
  }
```

Here I was trying to store the API details in finalAddress variable, but even if I write {{finalAddress.Message}} it gives me an error. If someone have a solution please help me.

Comment: What is angular version? In subscribe directly `console.log(val)`

Comment: You need 2 things here. 1. add ngModel field to state, district,village 2. use this getAdd function on keyup event of pinCode and bind those state, district, village to this.state, this.district and this.village

Comment: and you are already getting a JSON here so stringify is not required. You may need to restructure the data as it is an array of objects.

Comment: @Anonymous check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right direction. You need to modify your code slightly :

You need to add `[(ngModel)]`  to each of the input fields you want to populate the values. then assign them to the variables. The API returns multiple objects of address so you need to pick one (I picked first).

Update your code :

add these variables in the component :

```
  public state = '';
  public block = '';
  public district = '';
  public city = '';
```

then in html assign it to the respective input field :

```
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="state" />
```

update the add method as :

```
getAdd(pinCode) {
    this.httpClient
      .get(`https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/${pinCode}`)
      .subscribe((val) => {
        const [address] = val as any;
        this.finalAddress = address;
        console.log(this.finalAddress); // it returns multiple postOffices
        const postOffices = this.finalAddress.PostOffice;
        if (postOffices.length > 0) {
          this.state = postOffices[0].State;
          this.district = postOffices[0].District;
          this.city = postOffices[0].Name;
        }
      });
  }
```

Here is the working [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-upgqk7?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: what if I want to automatically fill the details as soon as the user enters the 6th digit of the Pin Code, that is I don't want that user press the button to fill the details rather automatically gets filled as soon as the 6th digit of Pin Code is entered

Comment: Then you can register keyup event on input instead of click event. When the input length is 6 make http call to fetch the data and then populate it